# How can I solve this equation if the lines are expressed in different forms?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the intersection of lines $L=(7,0,1) +\lambda(2,1,-2)$ and $Q : x+3=4-4y=20-4z$

Comment: Convert one of them into the same form as the other, if that's how you're used to intersecting two lines in $R^3$?

Comment: Yes, but the basic parametric form is x-x0=y-y0=z-z0 and I don't understand how I can convert it into that form

Comment: Into which form? Please be explicitly clear about which equation you want to convert into the alternative form.

Comment: Let's say both to be in vector form

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Okay, so for the vector form you need a point on the line and a/the direction vector. Would it help you to realize that $x+3 = 4-4y$ is the same equation as $\frac{x - (-3)}{1} = \frac{y-1}{-1/4}$?

Comment: (I'll add that what you reported as the "basic parametric form" isn't what I would expect. If it's the same thing I've learned, there can be stuff in the denominator.)

Answer (score 0):

Take your first equation. The meaning of that is $$(x,y,z)=(7,0,1)+\lambda(2,1,-2)$$
Or the equivalent:
$$x=7+2\lambda\\y=\lambda\\z=1+(-2)\lambda$$
For the second line, you can say that each of those terms is equal to $\mu$.
Then $$x+3=\mu\\4-4y=\mu\\20-4z=\mu$$
You can rewrite them to look like the first line:
$$x=-3+\mu\\y=1-\frac\mu4\\z=5-\frac\mu4$$
Can you take it from here?

Note that you can go back and forth between the two forms. If you want the second form, express $\lambda$ in the three components of the first line in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$.